# Can Slickgrid be used within EXTJS

Tags: extjs, slickgrid

I am trying to display possibly more than 100 000 rows of data at one go. Slickgrid looks like a potential candidate for this. However, my tool was already written in ExtJS and would just like to replace the gridpanel(loaded using jsonStore) in ExtJS with slickgrid. I tried to change the codes and tried to search for some samples of Slickgrid embedded in Extjs on the web but was unsuccessful. Does anyone has any idea or any sample codes which I can try? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check Sencha site for ExtJs samples - they have something called infinite grid: http://www.sencha.com/blog/infinite-grid-scrolling-in-ext-js-4

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, sha. I have read and tried the sample on ExtJs's infinite grid. It does not support selection yet and it appears quite slow, i.e. for a scroll, it takes a while to load the next batch of records. Hence, I think slickgrid is a  better option. Any idea on how I can integrate slickgrid in ExtJS?

Comment: We're using standard pagination with infinite grid in out project and it doesn't appear to be slow. I think slikgrid samples look faster but you need to compare apple and apples - i.e. see how slickgrid will work with your backend in real life situation. As far as integrating - you will have to solve several keys problem - styling it to the same way as ExtJs and integrating it to EextJs MVC ideology. It will be tough.

Comment: I see but pagination is not an option for us. Tried slickgrid with our data in pure HTML and it loads much faster. Yeah, agree that it is going to be real tough to integrate 2 libraries together. I am still trying it out. Let you know if it works. :)

Comment: When I say pagination - I don't mean we show to the user next/prev pages and other controls. We just load data page by page. But for user it's all one big grid.